# QGIS: How do I mirror a vector layer along a curve

Tags: qgis, point, curve

I want to mirror points alonge a curved line in QGIS. The points should exchange the positions.
[image]

My idea was to calculate the "shortest line between features". After that doing a "line intersections" to get the intersections betwenn the curved line and the shortest line . And finally, and here I have no idea, a kind of negative reflection.
Somebody have da idea to do this job well?
[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you add an image showing what result you expect, to avoid misinterpreting your question.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before, see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382627/88814

Comment: This solution works with straight or curved line segments, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9xit.png

Answer (score 0):

Using PostGIS with [STClosestPoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html) might be a solution. Find the nearest point on line and add the difference of coordinates to that point to find the mirror point. You can even simplify that : X_mirror = 2X_line - X